# Why is this Getter and Setter behaving like this?

Tags: php, oop

I recently came across this code question and am very unclear as to why it is producing these results.

```
Class Magic {
   public $a ="A";
   protected $b = array( "a"=>"A", "b"=>"B", "c"=>"C");
   protected $c = array(1,2,3);

   public function __get($v ) {
      echo "$v,";
      return $this->b[$v]; //internal so fine with protected.
   }

   public function __set($var, $val ) {
      echo "$var: $val,";
      $this->$var = $val;
   }
}

$m = new Magic();

//1
//echo $m->a;
//prints A

//2
//echo $m->a;
//echo $m->b;
//prints Ab, B

//3
//echo $m->a.",," . $m->b; 
//prints b,A,,B
```

I can not understand the behaviour for number 3. If somebody could explain I would be very appreciative as I can't find any answers anywhere on this behaviour.

I understand access modifiers and property visibility but I must have some gaps as not sure why 'b' is printing first as the getter calling the protected property is allowed to do so.

Additionally I would have thought 'A' would have printed first (like 1 and 2).
Find it strange why it behaves differently when it echoes both 'a' and 'b' at same time.

The only thing I can think is with `echo` 
-With the comma version, each argument is evaluated and echoed in turn
-The dot version is different, it has to be fully evaluated before it can be echoed as requested.
But not sure (how does it evaluate?).

Thanks

Comment: Could the person who downvoted please explain why?

Comment: I don't know but I found this question not wrong, well written, with example and self-try of the author, so I'll give you my vote up.

Comment: Thanks @Voitcus. Had 2 downvotes not sure why. It's a generic question from behaviour which seems strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the `echo` in `__get` method.
If you call `echo $m->a.",," . $m->b;` than first the functions inside statement get called.
So the `echo` in `__get` will be first called.

Comment: So the main 'echo' does not print anything until it has completed evaluating (I.e. hits it's ;)? Whether the getter echo prints rightaway?

Comment: yes, there are 2 operations here: first is string concatenation, and then the result of that concatenation is passed to your echo command to output. The thing is: by the time the concatenation is done, the internals of the getter have already echoed "b," to stdout, so when your echo happens, it's just appended to it.

Comment: Ah Yes think you are right. Check out this test http://codepad.org/EY3NdgDE . Seems obvious now lol. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

That has nothing to do with PHP OOP per say but with the order of evaluation of operands:

```
echo ($m->a . ",," . $m->b);
```

is a concatenation of 3 operands:

- $m->a : by itself **returns** "A"
- ,,: **returns** ",," (duh)
- $m->b does TWO things by calling $m->__get('b'): FIRST it **echos** "b," (in the getter function itself), THEN **returns** "B" for concatenation.

So by the time the 3 operands have been concatenated into one string "A,,B", the program has already echo-ed "b,". Then the concatenated string is passed to YOUR command echo for output, hence final result: "b,A,,B"

Comment: But would that not result in B printing before the A?

Comment: why would B print before A? Your concatenation does ("A" . ",," . "B"), which evaluates as expected to "A,,B". It's just that internally, when "B" is resolved, your getter has *already* echoed "b," to stdout.

Comment: Ah yes see what u mean, cheers just took me bit longer to see what u meant.